# Setting tool bar title in fragment with DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, material-design

Hi i am having a map fragment view inside a DrawerLayout. The activity look like this.

[image]

I want to add a title to the toolbar. i tried several option nothing worked. can some one help me to set the title for this activity.

**Activity_user_details**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context="zupportdesk.desk.zupport.chatsystem.UserDetails">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.learn2crack.myapplication.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/user_details_app_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>

            <include layout="@layout/content_user_details" />




        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/start_chat"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@drawable/button_style"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>




    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**content_user_details**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/user_details_app_bar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icone_avatar2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/ud_TV_name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Visitor ID"
        android:id="@+id/ud_TV_visitor_id"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ud_TV_name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ud_TV_name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ud_TV_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Start Time"
        android:id="@+id/ud_TV_start_time"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ud_TV_visitor_id"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity User Details**

```
public class UserDetails extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private String visitor_id;
    private String visitor_name;
    private String start_time;

    public String ProfileId;
    public String profileToken;
    public String CompanyID;
    public String DisplayName;

    TextView ud_name;
    TextView ud_visitor_id;
    TextView ud_start_time;

    private SelectVisitorService mService = new SelectVisitorService();
    private boolean mBound = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_details);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("zupportdesk", MODE_PRIVATE);
        ProfileId = prefs.getString("ProfileId", "Not defined");
        profileToken = prefs.getString("profileToken", "Not defined");
        CompanyID = prefs.getString("companyId", "Not defined");
        DisplayName = prefs.getString("DisplayName", "Not defined");

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        initNavigationDrawer();


        ud_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ud_TV_name);
        ud_visitor_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ud_TV_visitor_id);
        ud_start_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ud_TV_start_time);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        visitor_id = intent.getStringExtra("visitor_id");
        visitor_name = intent.getStringExtra("visitor_name");
        start_time = intent.getStringExtra("start_time");

        ud_name.setText(visitor_name);
        ud_visitor_id.setText(visitor_id);
        ud_start_time.setText(start_time);


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
```

**Manifest**

```
 <activity android:name=".UserDetails"
            android:label="User Details"/>
```

Comment: So you want to put some text next to the hamburger icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your Fragment is a static inner class, you can set a custom title to the ActionBar.

To do this, while using a custom layout, in your Fragment, call `getActivity().setTitle(YOUR_TITLE)`.

The reason you call `setTitle` is because you're calling `getTitle` as the title of your ActionBar. This returns the title for that Activity.

If you don't want to get call `getTitle`, then you'll need to create a public method that sets the text of your TextView in the Activity that hosts the Fragment.

In your activity you need to enter this code:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title){
    YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION_BAR_TITLE.setText(title);
}
```

Also, include this code in your fragment:

```
((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).setActionBarTitle(YOUR_TITLE);
```

**2015 Update:**

It seems that last year, Android have [updated](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) the way this is done. If you are building for later APIs, you need to use this:

In your fragment:

```
public class UpdateActionBarTitleFragment extends Fragment {
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public UpdateActionBarTitleFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction("Custom Title");
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_with_action_bar, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " needs to use OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void onFragmentInteraction(String title);
    }
}
```

In your activity:

```
public class UpdateActionBarTitleActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements UpdateActionBarTitleFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_action_bar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hi tnx. am getting the error `cannot resolve the method getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to put below lines to onCreate:

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

Comment: Error:(84, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)

Comment: try with replace setSupportActionBar() with setActionBar() and getSupportActionBar() with getActionBar() as your activity extends with Fragment Activity not AppCompatActivity. Let me know is it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, hope that helps

```
setActionBar(toolbar);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this logic help you

(First way):

In your fragment call add following code

```
getActivity().setTitle("your title");
```

(Second way):
call any type of function of your parent Activity or fragment class

```
YourActivity mActiviy = (YourActivity) getActivity();
mActivity.yourActivityFunction(yourParameters);
```

Comment: hi tnx. am getting the error cannot resolve the method getActivity().

Comment: Just remove getActivity() method because you are using Activity. getActivity() method generally use in inside onCreateView() .

Comment: another way use getActivity.getApplicationContext()